# Find where and how objects are used in Salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce

I have recently taken up salesforce.com and i have very little idea about its workings and stuff. Recently i was going through some of the stuff and i had a doubt...

Is there any way through which i can find out where an particular field/ object/ visualforce page has been used in an application. For example lets say i have a field labeled Sales, i want to be able to find where that particular field is used, under which object, and the object in which visualforce page/ Apex class, and the visualforce page/ Apex class is used in which application.

Hope i have made my Q clear.

Thanking everyone for their help

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a programming question, you might be better off asking about administrative stuff like that on salesforce.stackexchange.com.

If you have a test environment (sandbox) - you could always try deleting the field there ;) I'm kidding but if you'll try it the page should display you a list where the field is being used.

Similar thing could be achieved by creating a changeset, adding that field to it and then checking dependencies.

But probably the best way would require some preparations upfront. Read about Force.com IDE (or Eclipse IDE) and how to use it to download files that represent your object definitions, page layouts, classes, visualforce pages, reports... This is great as backup but also will let you search the files (Ctrl+H in Eclipse or just use whatever you want once you have the files locally). Search for API name of the field (similar to `My_Custom_Field__c` should be most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old thread but adding another option. I have a free and open source app that scans the fields in your Org and returns the components it's used in (Workflows, Processes, Page Layouts, Apex etc).

Keep in mind that returning fields in Apex and VF is not 100% accurate, as a field with the same API name on different objects would return as being found in a class, even though it might not (as others have mentioned).

Also, it can take quite a while to run on large Orgs.

App: http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/

Source Code: https://github.com/benedwards44/schemalister